# Please let me know the meaning of one sentence "Who knew that thing would top out at one twenty"

Tags: meaning, sentence

I have one question about drama dialogue.
Please see the sentence below and FYI, Vito is a criminal and it's the scene the case solved.

> Surprisingly, Vito's truck got all the way to Arizona before they nabbed him. **Who knew that thing would top out at one twenty, huh?**

I totally can't understand the second sentence. Could you help me?

Comment: It meant the speaker was surprised that the Vito's truck was able to reach a top speed of 120 miles per hour (~193 kilometers per hour). That's how was was able to get so far before being caught by his pursuers. For more details or if you have any follow-up questions, please ask on our sister site, dedicated to helping people learn English, [ELL.se].

Answer (score 2):

["Top out" means to reach a maximum of some value](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/top-out).

"One twenty" means "one hundred and twenty".

"That thing" refers back to the last subject, in this case "Vito's truck".

So the sentence expresses surprise that Vito's truck reaches a maximum of one hundred and twenty of some value - by implication speed: since it is in the US, it would be speed in miles per hour.